# Calling java.util.zip.Deflater.setInput multiple times does nothing after first time

Tags: java, http, gzip

I'm using java.util.zip.Deflater to compress an incoming stream of data received via an HTTP PUT, meaning that I get the data to be compressed in dribs and drabs, not all at once.  So my HTTP request handler repeatedly calls a method that looks like this as the data comes in:

```
byte[] compress(byte[] input) {
    byte[] output = null;
    if (this.compressor == null) {
        this.compressor = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION, true);

        // Add gzip header:
        output = getGzipHeader();
    }

    this.compressor.setInput(input);
    this.compressor.finish();

    while (!this.compressor.finished()) {
        byte[] tempOutput = new byte[10240];

        int compressedLength = this.compressor.deflate(tempOutput);

        if (output == null) {
            output = Arrays.copyOf(tempOutput, compressedLength);
        } else {
            byte[] newOutput = Arrays.copyOf(output, output.length + compressedLength);
            System.arraycopy(tempOutput, 0, newOutput, output.length, compressedLength);
            output = newOutput;
        }
    }

    // Update CRC:
    this.crc.update(input);
    this.byteCount += input.length;

    return output
}
```

And of course the class containing this method has instance variables:

```
private Deflater compressor;
private CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
private long byteCount = 0;
```

And once the last bytes have been received from the HTTP request, I append the CRC and total uncompressed length from the `crc` and `byteCount` instance variables.

As long as I send a very small amount of data in the HTTP PUT, this works great, because the `compress` method only gets called once.  I end up with a valid gzip file.  As soon as I send more than a few hundred bytes, resulting in `compress` getting called more than once, it does not work, because on all subsequent calls to `compress` after the first one, `this.compressor.finished()` returns true, even though I've called `this.compressor.setInput(input)` with the new input data.  If I look at `this.compressor.getBytesRead()` after all data has been processed, the value returned by that call is exactly the size of the first input buffer that came in (the first call to `this.compressor.setInput(input)`).  None of the subsequent calls to that method increase the value returned by `getBytesRead()`.

If I don't call `finish()` after the call to `setInput()`, it doesn't work at all -- I get no output.  But it seems like calling `finish()` is telling the `Deflater` not to accept *any* more input.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does this help: [DeflaterOutputStream](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.java#119) ?  (and would it make sense to just use this class directly?)

Comment: As jtahlborn said DeflaterOutputStream would greatly help. As a general comment, your code would look much simpler if you used `ArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(tempOutput))` instead of doing all that array manipulation yourself.

Comment: @jtahlborn, no, as far as I can tell, there is no way for me to use DeflatorOutputStream, because I don't have an output stream to write to. I probably should have mentioned that my service is built using [Vert.x](http://vertx.io), so I'm reading from a [ReadStream](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/index.html?io/vertx/core/streams/ReadStream.html) and writing to an [AsyncFile](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/index.html?io/vertx/core/file/AsyncFile.html). Data is received from a ReadStream in byte buffers and written to an AsyncFile in byte buffers.  No input or output streams.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, no, that would add the entire tempOutput buffer, including all the 0 bytes. And I'm looking for help with the problem at hand, being able to write compressed data based on reading in the input data stream in small chunks -- I'm not interested in general coding advice, thanks. This code has been simplified for this posting to attempt to clearly illustrate the specific issue.

Comment: you can implement an OutputStream which writes to an AsyncFile.

Comment: here's a simple (rather inefficient) version https://github.com/jdcasey/vabr/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/commonjava/vertx/vabr/util/VertXOutputStream.java

Comment: @jtahlborn, yes, that's true, you are absolutely correct, we could have gone that route.  We've tried to avoid adding any file (or AsyncFile, in this case) specific code to the transforms we do on the data stream, since we may write to file or we may write to an object store or we may send to cloud storage, all of which have completely different paradigms for writing the outgoing data stream.  This, since we're anyway tied to Vertx, we wanted to keep this as a simple transform from an incoming Vertx [Buffer](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/buffer/Buffer.html) to an outgoing Buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I basically copied the code almost verbatiim from `DeflaterOutputStream.write(...)` into my `compress` method, and copied from `DeflaterOutputStream.close()` into my own `finish` method, and it works great.

The trick here that is not explained even a tiny bit in the javadoc for `Deflater` (and in fact contradicts the example code shown in that javadoc) is that while receiving input, and calling `deflater.setInput(...)`, you only check for `!deflater.needsInput()`, and not for `!deflater.finished()`.  Then only once all input has been received, you call `deflater.finish()`, and then crucially, you then process any remaining data that may be pending in the `Deflater`'s buffer by looping `while (!deflater.finished())` and continuing to deflate any remaining data.

For details, just open up the source for `DeflaterOutputStream` and take a look at its `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` and `finish()` methods.